# Retrieve data from crossdomain api with authentication

Tags: ajax, rest

I wanted to know, how is the proper way to get data with javascript from a cross domain api that have authentication? So far, I know that JSONP is not an option because the browser will prompt my user to perfom a manual authentication. I try to do this with angular and I'm pretty new with it.

It's for sure that at this point I mix up many concepts, but I'm tired and confused trying to achieve something without the proper knowledge. Would you main to hihglight some basic concepts on this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) can be used as a modern alternative to the JSONP pattern, though it may not solve your issue with the browser prompting the user.

You may need to clarify what this browser prompt is as you can definitely use JSONP without any browser prompts. The only time I have known a browser to prompt is when making a `http://` JSONP call from a `https://` page. This is a security feature of some browsers and can be solved by serving your JSONP endpoint over HTTPS.